# mod_rewrite rules logging "Config variable ${REQUEST_URI} is not defined" on every request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the following .htaccess on an Apache/2.4.2-win32 server:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# Allow direct loading of files in the static directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?static/(.+)$ - [L]

# Send all other requests to controller
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/?(spf/index\.php)?$
RewriteRule .* spf/index.php [L,QSA]
```

This works well and does exactly what I want it to. For those of you who can't be bothered working out what it does, it sends all requests through `spf/index.php` unless they are for a file that exists in the `static` directory.

The file resides in the virtual host's documentroot.

Every request that falls through this .htaccess generates the following error:

```
[Wed Aug 01 14:14:16.549835 2012] [core:warn] [pid 7100:tid 1076] AH00111: Config variable ${REQUEST_URI} is not defined
```

This is not actually causing a problem - every request works as expected - but it's filling up my error log and I don't like it.

According to [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Config+variable+%24%7BREQUEST_URI%7D+is+not+defined%22), no-one has ever had this error before. That's as far as I've got with debugging it, I don't really know where to go next.

Anyone got any idea what's going on here?

*P.S. I'm aware this might be a question better suited to SF, if the general opinion is that it doesn't belong here I'll move it.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to replace the `$` with a `%`:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/?(spf/index\.php)?$
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(spf/index\.php)?$
```

Comment: *<facepalm>* Thank you. I knew it would be something obvious, I've just been staring at it for too long.

Comment: "According to Google, no-one has ever had this error before."

Now Google brings us all here, and I'm grateful because it saved me a few minutes—or more! _<facepalm>_

Comment: I made this error because of `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` having a `$`